# Do we need [getItem]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [getitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getitem) has 93 questions and no tag-wiki. It refers to very different methods (mostly Android or Python).

- Android Example: [Why getItem(position) works with a new instance? (should not be zero?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425089/why-getitemposition-works-with-a-new-instance-should-not-be-zero)
- Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320407/how-do-i-solve-a-no-attribute-getitem-error-from-a-code-with-integrated
- jQuery: [jQuery, Set Item In One Page, Display It In Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908826/jquery-set-item-in-one-page-display-it-in-another)

As you can see, these questions are no even remotely connected to each other (well, except the method name is the same).

Comment: It is also a MS Exchange method.

Comment: Well, it's also used in the scripting of some games...

Comment: I think Python usages should be migrated to [magic] (they are magic methods).  The rest should be burned.

Comment: Are any of the Python questions actually good questions, or are they all cases like "I passed None instead of an array and I got an exception that mentions something about get item not existing"? I can _imagine_ a Python question that might be usefully about `__getitem__` (e.g., implementing slicing on top of a class that only implements indexing), but I don't know that I've ever seen one.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: `[magic]` is for `things known as "magic strings" or "magic numbers". These are hard coded variables that cannot be changed at runtime.` That doesn't sound like a good place to throw questions about dunder methods.

Comment: @JasonMArcher No, they should probably be tagged by `overriding` or by `operators` or by `operator-overloading`, depending on the specific question. `__*__` method in python is the same as `operator*` in C++ so the same kind of tags should apply...

Comment: @abarnert, [magic] was [burninated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295011/is-there-a-place-for-magic) recently.

Comment: @JonasCz: Doesn't look like it was ever actually done...

Comment: @Deduplicator, I should have written "is _supposed_ to be burninated" then.

Comment: @JonasCz: After reading that, it sounds like maybe some Python questions should be migrated to `[magic-methods]` (but only the ones that actually are about `__getitem__` as a magic method; questions about `None[i]` are not about magic methods just because the exception description happens to mention one), and maybe some to `[operator-overloading]` or related tags, not to `[magic]`

Comment: No `[getItem].("burninator")` ? :(

Comment: Note that the tag [tag:magic] has magically disappeared from all the questions that used to be adorned with it.  OK, not magic — just some hard work by at least one person other than me, and a little of what we can pretend was work (…OK, not even all that much work, and not all that hard work…) by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag [getitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getitem) is now burninated!

I removed it from all android questions (mostly related to [Adapter#getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int))) and retagged all relevant Python questions to [magic-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-numbers).