# Is there a place for [magic]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

According to the tag wiki for [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic):

> Describes things known as "magic strings" or "magic numbers". These are hard coded variables that cannot be changed at runtime.

However, questions tagged with [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic) use it in another context: **Describing things they don't understand**. The tag doesn't add any meaningful information to the post.

Examples:

- [How to do Wake On LAN by Qt 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142457/how-to-do-wake-on-lan-by-qt-5)
- [Why bundle loses data type of top-level array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077480/why-bundle-loses-data-type-of-top-level-array)

Comment: Let's burn it ! ..Or cast an evil spell on it so it goes away forever :-)

Comment: There's no place for [tag:magic], only for [more magic](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html).

Comment: What is the color of [tag:magic]?

Comment: NO!  As the wiki states, the tag is for magic numbers, strings and methods.  The later is a real feature in PHP and Python.  However, there are some questions misusing the tag, and there are some related tags that probably need to be cleaned up ([python-magic] and [ipython-magic]).

Comment: [python-magic] could refer to half of Python.  The whole language is built out of hash tables and magical pixie dust.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I don't see anything in that tag description about magic methods.

Comment: @Kevin It actually refers to a library named python-magic.

Comment: @jwodder Yes, the wiki needs to be updated, or we could create a [python-magic-method] tag.

Comment: But... it even has a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_(programming))!

Comment: I'd rename it to "magic constants" or the like...

Comment: [Of course there's a place for magic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Note that "magic packets" are a real thing, relevant to wake-on-lan

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Before you wield your pitchforks and light your torches, there's a few other pieces here.

- [magic-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-methods) is a valid tag which relates to magic methods of any language.  Questions that are tagged with [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic) and explicitly discuss magic methods should be retagged to [magic-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-methods).
- [magic-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-string) and [magic-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magic-numbers) both exist in the system and have *some* relevance in the programming space (notably, how to avoid them and what they mean in the context of a static analysis tool like PMD).  If any question appears like it'd fit in those categories, I don't have any qualms about a retag to those tags.

At all times, **clean up the questions you're retagging.** Don't just remove the tag and call it good; it's a bit more involved than that.

Comment: I support this.

Comment: I've updated the tag wiki for [tag:magic] so it is pretty explicit that it should not be used, and outlines some alternative tags.  I've also edited a modest number of questions tagged with [tag:magic] so that they are not so tagged.  There are about 50 left to do.  (I think someone else may also be, or may have been, at work on the retagging.)

Comment: Someone else definitely helped; nearly 40 magic questions magically lost their magicality in the last 24 hours or so without me doing a thing — well, yes, I waved a wand about, but I don't think it really works!  However, as of right now, there are no questions left tagged [tag:magic].  It should vanish as a tag soon.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hah, [tag:magic] waved the wand, and came back.

Comment: @BhargavRao: we're down to about 16 now — the magic is fading!  FWIW: magic is a term used deep in the bowels of the Perl XS API (and internally) — I've not seen any questions about that, though, on SO.  It's a bit too specialized.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ah cool. There's [tag:ipython-magic], for those which are tagged [jupyter] or [python].

Comment: I mean, since we're all coordinating here, it was easy enough to intervene.  Seems like it'd be tempting to delete that question but I don't think seeing if libmagic can be cross-platform is inherently *poor*.