# The [deep] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The fact that the [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) tag exists sank in me recently, but it is in a state that I believe does not positively contribute to the site. It currently contains the following description:

> Anything related to so-called deep operations on recursive data structures, such as trees. A deep operation traverses the entire data structure, in contrast with "shallow" operations that only affect its "first level". For example, a deep-copy operation on a directory tree would copy the entire tree instead of copying only the content of the root directory.

However, the tag has actually been misused to refer to anything "deep", rather than just for questions about deep operations on (recursive) 
data structures. There are also a few cases where the question was about deep learning, but did not include the [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) tag as well. Given the exaggeratedly broad context of this tag, as well as the difficulty of keeping the tag self-contained to one subject (deep operations could also mean anything nonetheless), I propose we put it six feet under.

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

As a very common adjective, it does not accurately describe what it relates to. It must be always accompanied by some other concept, such as *copy*. The qualified subject might not even have a dedicated tag, making [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) pretty much confusing.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

The depths of on-topicness may vary. It depends on the rest of the question rather than this particular tag. Example, if it's used for deep learning questions, there's a significant chance that they're just bad (examples: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50322262/1233251)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49836792/1233251)]).

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It's occasionally been used for questions already tagged with [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning), in which case it is redundant. Other than that, the information it adds is misleading because the tag does not directly bind to its context.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. To name a few:

- It can mean structured data with an arbitrary depth, usually attainable with recursiveness (we have [recursive-datastructures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-datastructures)), and operations which are applied on them (for a deep copy, [deep-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-copy) exists);
- In deep learning, this relates to *deep* neural networks, which are artificial neural networks containing a large number of layers, thus giving them depth (see [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning));
- It was used to refer to deep linking (for which we have [deep-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-linking)).
- It has also been used to mean [how deep a certain stack trace goes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254759/1233251), which is arguably a bit pointless here;
- One particular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50660785/1233251) included it because of Deep Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA), which is purely about statistics and machine learning.

Comment: Some stats for the tag: [The tag has currently 195 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeep%5D+is%3Aquestion), 8 of them closed, and 95 with a score of 1 or higher.

Comment: To reinforce the point 4 (instead of justing having a "No" answer w/o justification), the tag has many meanings in the common context. Deep can either mean something that is "extending far down" (programming context - deeply nested structures), or something that is "very intense" (programming context - deep learning/coding/vision). In both of the cases, there are other tags that can be used.

Comment: @BhargavRao: When did "deep magic" fall out of use?

Comment: @Joshua, funny you ask about that, there were questions tagged with [tag:deep] and [tag:magic]. [magic] was burninated a few years back https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295066/4099593, and then it came back again, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295011/is-there-a-place-for-magic#comment627989_295066, after which it was re-burninated.

Comment: There's also the `/deep/` combinator used in CSS encapsulation, though a quick search only [returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473567/test-automation-with-polymer-2-piercing-the-shadow-dom-deep-deprecated) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020031/how-can-i-turn-off-deep-combinator-deprecation-warnings-in-chromes-console) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961302/the-selector-works-similarly-to-deep) that are actually tagged with [tag:deep].

Comment: Votes 2 hours after featuring: 89 (+90/-1), with 2 upvotes in the 3.6 hours of the UTC day that had expired as of the time this comment was posted. One answer at 6 (+6/-0) saying agree and that they had already edited some questions (2 upvotes today). One answer posted after featuring at 2 (+2/-0) agreeing that it should be burninated.

Comment: (OT) This is really deep.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery it's of historical interest only [/deep/ combinator in CSS is deprecated and will be removed in M63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348983/deep-combinator-in-css-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-m63)

Comment: I'd never heard of [`deep magic`](http://catb.org/jargon/html/D/deep-magic.html) until today.

Comment: *"It is in a state that I believe does not positively contribute to the site."* Well we need to go deeper...

Comment: Can we combine this with the [tag:state] tag?

Comment: @BobJarvis What do you mean with "combine"?

Comment: I am sorry, but who came up with the phrase burninate? Its sounds like something Strong Bad would write.

Comment: @needoriginalname It's one of the many [memes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/282465) of SO.

Comment: @artem It's still valid Angular though, as the answer to that question states.  Not enough to warrant its own tag, sure, but I was just adding in another meaning for the term.

Comment: @needoriginalname not only does it sound like something Strong Bad would write, it is a reference to Trogdor.

Comment: Can we *please* make it harder to create tags? The need for new tags is quite rare these days, and I think Meta would much more gladly handle tag *creation* than trying to clean up the mess left by millions of people who didn't care.

Comment: @jpmc26 _"Can we please make it harder to create tags?"_ That would make a nice Meta question title (not that I fully agree with the idea).

Comment: @jpmc26 I already have such a question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366403/can-we-stop-the-flow-of-burnination-requests-by-limiting-the-amount-of-tags-crea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) for questions about AI/neural networks
- Use [deep-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-copy) for anything about copying data
- Use [deep-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-linking) for questions about links

## Progress:

The [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=deep),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeep%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeep%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeep%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeep%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 26):

As a stand alone tag, [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep) doesn't have any relevance for the site. As mentioned, the programming references to the word "deep" are compound words like [deep-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-copy). Unless there's something that's been missed in the discussion, I recommend we burn it.

It's important to not go ahead and re-tag questions until we have a community consensus. Then we do so following the [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

Comment: I've just read this now, and will stop re-tagging unless I spot [deep] where [deep-learning] would fit. I agree that [deep] doesn't make sense by itself. At the very least, when we burninate the tag, some of those that were poorly tagged have at least one more appropriate tag.

Comment: @icedwater it's better if you do nothing until there's a community consensus. Then we make a coordinated effort. By retagging you're making the assumption the tag is going, before it's been approved that the tag is going. Have a look in this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor where there's a coodinated effort on burns

Comment: Any chance of the request being featured through its completion (or at least a little longer so that everyone knows that the request is approved)? Or do I need to write a separate Meta post proposing that that be part of the process?

Comment: @EJoshuaS featured

Answer (score 16):

I agree with your assessments above; I've trimmed the fat a little by replacing some tags on the deep-linking and deep-learning type questions.

Perhaps some others who have "[deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep)er" knowledge of the questions can propose better, more specific tags.

Maybe [this stack trace question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254759) could have a [depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth) tag instead.

Comment: Just for future reference, please read up on [the full burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). Sometimes burninates look popular but wind up in cleanup instead of burninate